# the problem with wi-fi u2

Tags: drivers

right here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1716301 a person writes that he has found a solution to the problem with connecting the tenda u2 wi-fi on the mt7601 chip in Ubuntu, attaches a patch script to solve this problem. I do not know how to do it, help! maybe something is missing?

`in addition:` I installed a patch on kernels 5.4.0 and 5.4.206. yesterday there was a change in the wi-fi work plan. both cores behaved the same way. the device began to be detected every time it was connected, I saw the network, but I couldn't connect to it. went to bed. I get up, start the system, the device is not detected. dmesg writes about the same errors on the driver, sorry, I can't remember exactly. In general, this patch is crooked, because I was never able to connect to the network. Question is there another patch for this driver that I could apply?

`here is more detail:`  [ubuntu v/ 18.04/20.04. wi-fi tenda u2 (mt7601u)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418382/ubuntu-v-18-04-20-04-wi-fi-tenda-u2-mt7601u)

Comment: MT7601U drivers are included since kernel 4.2. Which Ubuntu/release version are you using? If 16.04 as in your link please be aware it's out of support and off-topic here.

Comment: read below. this is the post   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1716301/comments/53 . I am using version 18 or 20. the error is present in all versions for this Wi-Fi adapter.

Comment: 1) How to do it is too broad for AU. If you don't know how to patch a kernel, then the solution is not for you. 2) There is no Ubuntu 18 or 20.

Comment: And I was hoping for help here! is it really so difficult to explain with a concrete example how to do this or why it is impossible? I just need to get a device that can work, the driver for which is already in ubuntu, but the fix for which the developers for some reason did not make it into the system. I don't care about the risks at all, I'm on a virtual machine, and even if Ubuntu is on hardware, I'm not interested in the risks, I'll delete the operating system and install it. I have a problem!

Comment: OK. I can tell you how to do it. 1) Download kernel source; 2) Apply the patch; 3) Build the kernel; 3) Install the kernel.

Comment: And if Ubuntu is in a virtual machine, you don't need to install anything to Ubuntu. You can use the device on the host and use the internet connection on a guest.

Comment: So this is a VM? Are you by any chance trying to use the WiFi directly but forgot to passtrough the USB and that's why you think you need to do something to make it work? As above, it's seldom needed to use the WiFi directly in any VM and unless you pass it to the VM (automatically disconnects from the host OS) then it should work with the virtualized Ethernet device regardless of the actual device/connection in the host OS.

Comment: I need to use a vm for the convenience of solving the problem. it doesn't matter where linux is, it doesn't work with my Wi-Fi. I need to fix the problem before I reinstall it on my hardware. once again, in order for the adapter to start on linux, you have to run Windows with this adapter, and then crash it! only after all these actions does the adapter work, until the first reconnection

Comment: I searched the Internet for a very long time, but found only a post with a script. I do not know what to do with it. it would be easier if there was a corrected driver file.

Comment: oh, and yes, I can run the adapter on the vm in the same way as in the case of real hardware, the difference is that I do not need to restart the PC. however, after the first reconnection, the adapter does not work.